# Placeholder is replaced with label text

Tags: 8, webforms

I am new in Drupal Community,
I am trying to create a form using webform module in drupal 8, i have setup the placeholder for textfield but it won't show on the form, its taking label as placeholder. i have spent a lot of time to check the settings but unable to find such setting can any one help me to resolve this issue,

attaching screenshot of textfield setting and from:

[image]

[image]

please check above ss from your ref and help.

thanks in advanced.

my field.html.twig is:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,
    label_display == 'inline' ? 'clearfix',
  ]
%}
{%
  set title_classes = [
    'field__label',
    label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'visually-hidden',
  ]
%}

{% if label_hidden %}
  {% if multiple %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field__items') }}>
      {% for item in items %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    <div{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label }}</div>
    {% if multiple %}
      <div class="field__items">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if multiple %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the field.html.twig that renders this field? It might be possible that your theme prints the label as a placeholder in the twig file which overwrites the behaviour of webform?

Comment: where we can find this file?

Comment: i have found this at /core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig:

Comment: updated question twig file.